# Random Chrome's print preview (scaling) behavior

Tags: html, css

I'm having random scaling issues when printing the content in Google Chrome. When the content is repainted, the scale is altered for no apparent reason.
I use web components with their styles embedded in their respective shadow doms so it's hard for me to share all the styles here.

Thanks

[image: random print preview behavior]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was an animated progress bar component with "visibility: hidden". It seems that if the bar position exceeded the full width of the container at paint preview time, the overall scale would decrease.
In others browsers this hidden progress bar was ignored.